# Does a singleton create retain cycle inside block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, singleton, objective-c-blocks

I have a singleton and I want to capture it inside a block. I know that variables are retained inside a block because a constant copy of the objects passed is created and never deallocated unless using a weak instance of that object. The curiosity I have is whether the same behaviour is applied to a statically allocated variable.
Here is my code (self is the sharedInstance of Class):

```
    + (Class *)sharedInstance
    {
        static Class *sharedInstance = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedInstance = [[Class alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedInstance;
    }

    [self setBlock:^(NSArray *array)
    {
        self.property = [array firstObject];
    }];
```

Comment: That's not _exactly_ how blocks work but yes, the same behavior is applicable for your singleton as any other object.

Comment: When you use an object reference inside of a block, the _reference_ is copied which adds +1 to the reference count that ARC uses (when your reference is strong). It does _not_ copy the object itself. Copying a weak reference does not increment the reference count.

Comment: I understand. Very good answer. Appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: The copied reference that the block captures has the same lifetime as the block itself. When that reference also has a reference to block that references it... well, you've got a retain cycle.

Comment: Yes, this introduces a strong reference cycle (formerly known as retain cycle) of `self`, the singleton. But your singleton is never released anyway, so this isn't a source of any leaks. Still, I'd be inclined to use the `weakSelf` pattern in case you later use this object as something other than a singleton.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the actual case, no leaks, but Xcode still gives me warnings when I do it :). I wanted a confirmation that this is fine from the memory point of view, I did not know before that no copies are created whatsoever and that blocks just create references. Thank you all for the clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim that “a constant copy of the objects passed is created” is incorrect.  The block creates `__strong` or `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained` references to the objects that it uses; it doesn't copy the objects.

Your code creates a retain cycle between `self` and the block object, because the block has a strong reference to self and (assuming `self.property` is strong) `self` has a strong reference to the block.

The compiler doesn't understand the concept of a singleton.  It doesn't know there's anything special about the lifetime of `sharedInstance`.  So it doesn't do anything different with the block just because you've set up `self` as a singleton.

Comment: +1 Tho, often `self.property` is defined as `copy` rather than `strong`, but your point still applies as it still maintains strong references to the captured variables.

Comment: The question is about the lifecycle of "self" as much as it is about strong and weak properties.   There isn't a retain cycle because the strong reference doesn't result in a leak.

Comment: I agree that there's no leak, because `sharedInstance` is a root of the object graph and `sharedInstance` references the singleton. However, the question was (literally) “Does a singleton create retain cycle inside block?” and there is certainly a retain cycle between the singleton and the block in this case. Not all retain cycles are leaks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the block will retain the singleton forever!  But the singleton is always going to be in memory.  So, there is nothing to be released.  Hence, there is absolutely no reason to use weakSelf if the self object is a singleton.  A singleton is an object that lives in memory forever.